# Automated source text animation based on split

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I have newly started in AE and I came across source text animation.

I have a requirement where I want to show multiple text on source text keyframe animation. I was wondering instead of writing each text on the keyframe is there a way to automate this.

For example, I have created two text layers and the empty layer is referring to the data source (text source) and I know how to split them based on a delimiter. Please refer to the screenshot.

```
t=thisComp.layer("test1-test2-test3").text.sourceText;
word=t.split("-");
word[2]
```

Now, Is there a way for me to tell AE to increase the value dynamically inside word[] in line 3 by +1.

If possible, I desire the code to return word[0] at 0000; word[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdlAb.png)] at 0001 and word[2] at 0002.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it

```
t=thisComp.layer("test1-test2-test3").text.sourceText;
word=t.split("-");
n = time/thisComp.frameDuration
word[n]
```